# Is there a way to select a project using ENVDTE?

Tags: c#, com, envdte

I want to add a Service reference to a project using ENVDTE. The only way is by the following command which pops up the Add service Reference window:

```
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Project.AddServiceReference", string.Empty);
```

But this command will work only on currently selected project. Is there a way to select a particular project where the service reference is to be added?

`DTE2.SelectedProjects` has no way to select a project, it only helps to retrieve selected projects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate through the solution tree like this :

```
var se = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;  
var proj = se.GetItem("PathToYourProject");
proj.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
```

After you launch your command.

PathToYourProject is a "pseudo" XPath. If you're workging in a project called "Project" in a solution called "Solution" your path will be : "Solution\Project"

Take care if your project is in a solution folder. It's a little bit more tricky. You have to expand solution folder like this :

```
var solutionFolder = se.GetItem("PathToYourSolutionFolder");
if (!solutionFolder .UIHierarchyItems.Expanded)
{
    solutionFolder .UIHierarchyItems.Expanded = true;
}
```

Then you retrieve and select your project by this way :

```
var proj = solutionFolder .UIHierarchyItems.Item("ProjectName");
proj.Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
```

Finally, I'm not sure, but you may have to select the "Service References" node of your project before to launch the command.